# How to disable googlebot in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Yesterday googlebot caused my app to exceed read quotas. How do I disable googlebot? Thanks.

**Update**

I added

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_dir: robots
```

to my `app.yaml` [as explained here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html) and created the `robots.txt` file the directory "robots", but the url `http://www.example.com/robots.txt` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should move the robot route above some catch all route like `/.*` you probably have in your `app.yaml`

Comment: @systempuntoout: sorry, `http://localhost:8086/robots/robots.txt` works. Is that how it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the robot route above the  /.* catch all route and modify your `app.yaml` with:

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots/robots.txt
  upload: robots/robots.txt
```

Bear in mind that this action will affect the SERP of your application (Google will de-index your app sooner or later)

Answer (score 5):

Add a [`robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/). Here is a simple one which blocks all robots that heed it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if it is enough just to put in the app directory?

Comment: @Zeynel: You need to make it so when you access `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`, you get the file. (obviously, replace `www.example.com` with your domain) I don't remember how to do that in App Engine, but it should be pretty simple.

Comment: @Zeynel: If you're using Python, [see here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html). If you're using Java, [see here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html). Google doesn't appear to have any documentation for static files with Go.

Comment: I updated the question. I added the robots.txt as static file but the link is not working

Comment: @systempuntoout: at this point I am the only user and I can live without being indexed for now